# Understanding the Proof: Assumption about infinite set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

**Problem:**

Let $X$ be a metric space and $C \subset X$ be a non-empty closed set. Show that if $x \notin C$ then $D(\{x\}, C)>0$, where
$$
D(A, B):=\inf \{d(x, y) \mid x \in A, y \in B\}.
$$

**Provided Solution:**

Assume that $D(\{x\}, C)=0$. This means that there is a sequence $\left\{x_n\right\}$ such that $x_n \in C$ and $d\left(x_n, x\right) \rightarrow 0$. Since $x \notin C$, this means that $x$ is a limit point to $C$. But $C$ is closed and therefore contains all its limit points. Thus we get $x \in C$, which contradicts the assumption that $x \notin C$. In summary: the assumption that $D(\{x\}, C)=0$ leads to a contradiction. So we must have $D(\{x\}, C)>0$.

**Question:**

My question is about the existence of the sequence $\left\{x_n\right\}$. To me it looks like this would require $C$ to be an infinite set, because if $C$ were finite, it wouldn't be possible to create an infinite sequence of points in $C$ that converge to $x$. It is my understanding that $\left\{x_n\right\}$ must have an infinite number of unique points to be able to converge to $x$, since $x \notin C$.

Am I correct in understanding that this proof inherently assumes $C$ to be infinite? Or am I misunderstanding something fundamental about sequences and convergence in metric spaces?

I appreciate any insights or clarifications!

Comment: A sequence $x_n$ in $C$ is not a subset of $C$ but a function $x:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow C$. $x_n$ can take only finitely many values. For example if $C=\{1,2\}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. Any sequence in $C$ takes at most two different values. the point $2$ is an accumulation point of $C$;  the sequence $x_n=1$ for $1\leq n\leq 10$ and $x_n=2$ for $n>10$ is a sequence in $C$ that converges to $2$.

Comment: @Mittens Yes, that is true. I say $\{x_n\}$ in $C$ as shorthand for $x_n \in C$, maybe this is confusing. Although I don't see how. As for the set $C = \{ 1, 2 \}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, I don't see how $2$ is a limit point (I assume 'accumulation point' is the same as 'limit point') of $C$. In fact, if we look at the neighborhood $N = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: |x-2| < .1\}$, we see that there is no $p \neq 2$ in $N$ such that $p \in C$, hence it's per definition not a limit point. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: there are is a problem of semantics. A cluster point or limit point $x$ of a set $C$ in a topological space $X$ is a point in $X$ such that for any open set $V$ containing $x$, $C\cap(V\setminus\{x\})\neq\emptyset$. Sometimes, authors also use the term accumulation point. What I meant is  *closure point* of $C$: a point $x\in X$ such that for any open set $V$ containing $x$, $V\cap C\neq\emptyset$. This includes list points of $C$ as well as *isolated points*.  In metric spaces, a point $x$ is a *closure point* of $C$ iff there is a sequence $x_n$ in $C$ that converges to $x$.

Comment: In my example from first comment, $2$ is a closure point of $C=\{1,2\}$.

Comment: It seems worth pointing out that your instinct that $C$ needs to be infinite is not  completely off-base, it was just confused by the distinction between a sequence and the set of its values. What is true is that if $C$ is a subset of $(X,d)$ and there is a point $x\in X$ with $d(\{x\},C)=0$ but $x \notin C$, then $C$ must be infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not correct since sequences are allowed to have repeated terms, but on the other hand you are correct since all finite sets are closed, so the situation $d(x,C)=0$ could only happen if $C$ were infinite.

Example: the metric space is $\Bbb R$, $x=0$ is the origin and $C=\{0.5,1,2\}$ which is a closed set not containing $x$.

The distance $d(x,C)$ is $0.5$. There is indeed a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of elements of $C$ such that $d(x_n,x)\to0.5$. There are many... for instance, the constant sequence $x_\bullet\equiv 0.5$. $C$ does not need to be infinite for this theorem to apply.

*However*, if $C$ is some set, $x\notin C$ and $d(x,C)=0$ then it *must* be the case that $C$ is infinite (and also that $C$ is not closed).

Comment: I see your point when we don't assume $x \notin C$ and $D(\{x\}, C)=0$. Maybe my confusement lie in the nature of proofs by contradiction. It seems like we have two inconsistencies, firstly that $C$ must be an infinite set (meaning the statement could not be true in general if this is not stated), secondly the outright contradiction that $x \in C$ and $x \notin C$. More so, it seems like you are saying that one could also demonstrate the contradiction that $C$ is both closed and not closed. What conclusion can one draw from this? Sorry if I'm all over the place!

Comment: Facts: (1) If $C$ is closed and $x$ is not in $C$ then $D(\{x\},C)>0$. (2) If $C$ is a (nonempty) subset of a metric space and $x$ is not in $C$, $D(\{x\},C)=0$ implies that $C$ is infinite (and not closed). (3) If $C$ is a finite set, it is closed and the situation: "$x$ is not in $C$ and $D(\{x\},C)=0$" never occurs.

Comment: The proof by contradiction does **not** need to assume $C$ is infinite in order to work. Whatever the value of $D(\{x\},C)$ is, there will be some sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\subseteq C$ with $d(x,x_n)\to D(\{x\},C)$

Answer (score 2):

There is no ned for $C$ to be infinite. In metric spaces, a point $x$ belongs to the closure of a set $C$ iff there is a sequence in $C$ which converges $x$ ($x$ could be either an isolated point of $C$ or a cluster point of $C$).

A more direct proof of the segment perhaps, is to consider $x\in X\setminus C$. If $C$ is closed, then $X\setminus C$ is open and so, there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that the open ball $B(x;\varepsilon) \subset X\setminus C$. This means that for any $y\in C$,
$d(x,y)\geq\varepsilon$; hence $d(\{x\},C)\geq\varepsilon$